# How to change Html div background using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**How to change Html div background using Javascript**

```
<div id="div" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Try This **

```js
document.getElementById("div").style.background= "red";
```

```html
<div id="div" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
```

Comment: I suggest to set `backgroundColor`. `background` overwrites other styles as well.